# Ignore carriage return for a specific file with Git

Tags: unix, git, newlines, carriage-return

I use multiple environments thanks to virtual machines, and my code directory is shared between them. I also like my code to have the native (host) line endings.

When I'm on a Windows host, I checkout my code and line endings are converted to `\r\n` (and it's OK for me). But when I want to execute a shell script from my Linux virtual machine, I get errors telling me the `/bin/sh^M` doesn't exist.

**Can I tell Git to keep Unix endings for this *specific* file?** Is there a better way to deal with line endings on multiple environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single file, create a [`.gitattributes`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) file containing:

```
*.sh    eol=lf
```

(Another possible setting is `-text`, which simply disables line ending conversion.)

Comment: `-text` will do other things too that you don't want, like stop showing diffs for the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can run [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) on the files to format them properly for linux/unix.

Comment: It would make the file look completely different to the VCS.